# Are there Realease Notes when a new Release is published?

Tags: upgrade

There is a new Civi release about every fortnight (or even less) (currently 5.18.1).

Updating one's configuration at every release is painful and risky (you may have regressions) ; but it can also be very useful (bug fixes, ans enhancements).

So, it would be very useful to know what changes are brought by a new release.

... which is the usual purpose of Release Notes.

I could not find such assciated release notes. Are there any ? If yes, where can we find them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should find release notes for all versions linked from https://civicrm.org/blog/tags/release (this page is linked from the download page). Maybe they haven't added in the latest yet: 5.18.0 not there either

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/blob/master/release-notes.md links to all the release notes including 5.18.0 and 5.18.1

Comment: Thank you Mick. But it is not intuitive. I would suggest a link in each release download page.

Comment: Yes, I agree its not perfect. Certainly there should be a link to the release notes for the latest release. The release blog only seems to include major and security releases.